# "No-referrer" meta tag can blank the referral & prevent third-party website to find my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, referrer

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

I want to blank the referral. Let say, my website is `example.com` has URL `facebook.com` and someone clicked `facebook.com` in my website and they redirect to `Facebook.com`. Then `Facebook.com` will know this user came from `example.com` (My website) and even it will shown in there analytics.

I want to hide my website from third-party website getting tracked due to referral. Just want to confirm do above tag will work and do the job which i am looking for?

Comment: `No-referrer` and `None` do same work right?

Comment: @MarkusZeller somewhere i also saw `<meta name="referrer" content="never">`

Comment: I'd use `never`, too as stated in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#meta-referrer I've read `none` in some SEO guides.

Comment: @MarkusZeller total confused. which one should i use `No-referrer` or `None` or `never`

Comment: Prefer `never`, because that is officially documented as linked in my comment above.